# Chrome debugger breaks at launch even without a breakpoint when started from Node.js VS Code project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I launch my application, the Chrome Debugger immediately stops. I don't have any breakpoints. This is a really annoying behavior.

I launch my app with `node --inspect-brk` and launch the debugger (once) with `chrome://inspect/` and click on Open dedicated DevTools for Node.

I followed [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/debug-node-js-using-google-chrome-and-visual-studio-code-5521c5e8f30c) guide and it actually states that

> When we open DevTools, the source code appears in the browser which has loaded while running our application and will be paused at the first line.

I hate this, how can I turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out. The `--inspect-brk` switch breaks when the debugger attaches. There's a regular `--inspect` flag instead.